# Excel VBA - Multiple copy of a sheet with different names

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Sheets -Entry & Master.
I want x No of copies of Master with a macro.
If in Entry sheet A1 has value - 1 copy
A1 & A2 have values - 2 copies
A1&A2&A3  have values - 3 copies ... 
likewise up-to 5 copies If A1:A5 Selected

Each copied sheet name should be the values of A1 to A5

```
Sub CopyMaster()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Visible = xlSheetVisible
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets("Entry").Range("A1").Value) Then
    MsgBox ("Cannot Copy.. Please Check Your Selection")
Else
    Worksheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet1.Name = Worksheets("Entry").Range("A1").Value
    ActiveSheet2.Name = Worksheets("Entry").Range("A2").Value
    MsgBox ("Successfully created.... x Copies")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**edited**:

- added new worksheet renaming
- added possible worksheet name duplication handling

may be this is what you are after:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMaster()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nSheets As Long

    With Selection '<--| reference selection
        If .Parent.Parent.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then '<--| check for referenced (selected) cells to be in the proper workbook
            If .Parent.Name = "Entry" Then '<--| '<--| check for referenced (selected) cells to be in the proper worksheet
                If Not Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then '<--| check for referenced (selected) cells to be in column "A"
                    For Each cell In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through referenced (selected) non blank cells
                        If Not existentWorksheet(cell.value) Then '<--| if no sheets with current cell name already ...
                            Worksheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count) '<--| ... make a new copy of master workbook
                            ActiveSheet.Name = cell.value '<--| rename it
                            nSheets = nSheets + 1 '<--| update copied worksheets counter
                        Else
                            MsgBox "worksheet '" & cell.value & " already in " ' & ThisWorkbook.Name, vbCritical + vbOKOnly
                        End If
                    Next cell
                    If nSheets > 0 Then MsgBox "Successfully created " & nSheets & IIf(nSheets > 1, " copies", "copy"), vbInformation + vbOKOnly
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function existentWorksheet(shtName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    existentWorksheet = Worksheets(shtName).Name = shtName
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example function to copy worksheets, please pay attention how I use a typed variables for pretty much everything. It makes your life easier once functions grow complexity. Also see a reference library being used for importing dictionary array object.

I leave it to you handle a hidden worksheet issue as it may affect `worksheets.count` use.

```
Option Explicit
' Tools/References
' [x]Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Public Sub CopyMaster()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wsEntry As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim arrNames As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim copied As Long
    Dim sName As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsCurrent = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set wsMaster = wb.Worksheets("Master")
    Set wsEntry = wb.Worksheets("Entry")
    Set arrNames = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' check for conflict worksheet names first
    For idx = 1 To 5
        sName = Trim(wsEntry.Cells(1, idx))
        If (sName <> "") Then
            If isWorksheet(wb, sName) Or arrNames.Exists(sName) Then
                Call MsgBox("Worksheet name " & sName & " conflict")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Call arrNames.Add(sName, "")
        End If
    Next

    ' copy worksheets
    copied = 0
    For idx = 1 To 5
        sName = Trim(wsEntry.Cells(1, idx))
        If (sName = "") Then GoTo ContinueLoop
        wsMaster.Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        Set wsNew = wb.ActiveSheet  ''Set wsNew = wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        wsNew.Name = sName
        copied = copied + 1

ContinueLoop:
        ' next step
    Next
    wsCurrent.Activate
    Call MsgBox("Created " & copied & " copies")
End Sub

Private Function isWorksheet(wb As Workbook, sName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    isWorksheet = False
    isWorksheet = Not wb.Worksheets(sName) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**edit** added Scripting.Dictionary to handle tuple names.

Answer (score 0):

No new worksheets will be added if cell values in `[Entry!A1:A5]` are duplicated or have a worksheet with the same name.  If either of these conditions occur, the cell containing the bad value is highlighted and a message will appear showing the bad values.  If all values are valid a message will appear showing the number of worksheets created.

---

```
Sub CopyMaster()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rEntries As Range, r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim msg As String
    Dim list(1) As Object
    Set list(0) = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set list(1) = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Worksheets("Master").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        list(0).Add ws.Name
    Next

    Set rEntries = Worksheets("Entry").Range("A1:A5")
    For Each r In rEntries
        If r.Text <> "" Then
            If list(0).Contains(r.Text) Or list(1).Contains(r.Text) Then

                msg = msg & r.Value & vbCrLf
                r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else
                list(1).Add r.Text
                r.Interior.Color = -4142
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Len(msg) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot Copy.. Please Check Your Selection" & vbCrLf & msg, vbInformation, "Try Again"
        GoTo EnableScreenUpdating
    End If

    For Each r In rEntries
        If r.Text <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = r.Text
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox ("Successfully created.... " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(rEntries) & "  Copies")

EnableScreenUpdating:
    Worksheets("Master").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```